# Using the new operator with a variable

Tags: javascript, new-operator

I'd like to do something like this:

```
var foo = function(){
   this.value = 1;
}
var bar = "foo";
var baz = new bar();
alert(baz.value)     // 1
```

Essentially, I want to create a new object from the string version of its name. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var foo = function(){
   this.value = 1;
};
var bar = "foo";
var baz = new this[bar](); // "this" here refers to the global object (you could also use "window", but "this" is shorter)
alert(baz.value)     // 1
```

See also http://blog.brett-zamir.me/?p=24

Comment: Assuming it is a global variable :)

Comment: Yes. Otherwise, there is no generic local scope object available to script.

Comment: How would you do this if you were not in the global scope? For instance, what if we wrapped that snippet into a self executing function: `(function(){ ...snippet... })();`